# UITableView display and reload behavior is out of sync

Tags: ios, uitableview, viewdidappear

I've looked at other UITableView questions, but did not find any that matches this scenario.

I have a normal UITableViewController that accepts an array from a search form (IOW, dynamic data). The form has a push segue to the table VC, and the table cells have another push segue to a 'details' type of screen for each item. In the table view, I call reloadData in viewDidAppear.

The first time I test the search, the table displays the "no results" view (in a screen-wide cell) that I programmed into it, but only for about 1 second. After that, the search results appear as expected and the navigation works fine.

How can I get rid of this initial glitch?

EDIT: (@Paulw11's request) The search operation is network-based, and I call performSegueWithIdentifier in the dispatch_get_main_queue block. The data is passed in prepareForSegue as an NSArray (with multiple items per index).

Comment: You need to distinguish between the case where there are no search results (indicated by, say, an empty array) and the case where the search is not yet complete (say a `nil` optional array) and return 0 for number of rows in the latter case. You should edit your question to show your code in order to get a better answer

Comment: If the search involves a network operation then I would suggest some sort of user feedback, such as activity indicator view, while that network operation is taking place.

Answer (score 0):

This was actually an issue with the segue from the search controller to the table firing twice.

In my case, this was caused by the segue being wired to the search button instead of to the search view controller itself.